# russian roulette odd way to count that confuses me

Tags: swift, math, probability

so i'm making this game about russian roullette

it starts wit 5 bullets out of 6 chamber
then whenever the person lives
one bullet is removed

is my way of doing it mathematicly accurate

the bullet count is based on the amount of characther on my button

heres my code

```
@objc func clickedTrigger(){
    attempts += 1
    if GKRandomDistribution.d6().nextInt() > gunTrigger.title.count{
        if gunTrigger.title.count == 1{
            gunTrigger.title = "⁍⁍⁍⁍⁍"
            NSSound(named: NSSound.Name(rawValue: "Glass"))?.play()
            attempts = 0
            appWindow.title = "you won the game"
        }
        else{
            gunTrigger.title = String(gunTrigger.title.dropLast())
            appWindow.title = "the person dodged a bullet."
        }
    }
    else{
        gunTrigger.title = "⁍⁍⁍⁍⁍"
        appWindow.title = "the person saddly died."
    }
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work as it should? Can you add this to the question?

Comment: @chistik, everything seems to work just fine im just not sure that coded this way it gives accurate stastic of 5/6 chances when theres 5 bullet ten 4/6 when theres 4 bullets

Comment: You need to form a random sample such as {0,1,0,0,0,0} and then with random index start and then check the index with index mod 6. If it is 1, then over, else continue.

Comment: good response @macroland but do u know why the way i do it isnt accurate it seems that it would be tho?

Comment: @macroland you should post that as an answer